# What are the benfits of inheritance over template based data structures?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'll get to the point and explain below.

What, if any, are the benefits of...

```
template<class T>
class myStack : public myList<T>...// my stack
```

over

```
template<class T, Container = deque<T> >
class stack...// C++ stack
```

Recently I was writing some code and was faced with an inheritance issue where I was exposing aspects of the base class that I would rather not. The specific example isn't important so I'll relate it to few semesters ago when I took a data structures class where we implemented our own list, stack, queue and others.

In this class we were to design a stack which was to inherit from a list. The problem with this was I was exposing public methods of the base that could potentially damage the stack's integrity. It may be that I'm a bit of a purist but having the `insert()` and `remove()` lying around in the stack was bothersome for me. I didn't have time to investigate it then but this time I thought I would consult the C++ standard to see how the `stack` was defined there. Low and behold I found the code above; it was an obvious solution that I overlooked.

Here's my view...

The C++ implementation is "better" because it allows the user the freedom to choose the underlying structure if desired and maintains a more pure stack in that it is clear only stack functionality available to the user and can be more guarded from unintended corruption. Are there more substantial, non-subjective reasoning behind the design choice, or inherit flaws in it?

The obvious benefit of mine is code re-use which is par for the course, I don't see that as an additional benefit the way I personally see the benefit of the freedom with the C++ implementation. I do see the over exposure (my words) of the base class as a con though. Are there more substantial, non-subjective reasoning behind the design choice, or inherit flaws in it?

Again, I'm not concerned with languages, I'm more concerned with weighing the pros/cons for my own designs.

Comment: Java is from 1995. STL implementations started to pop up around 1994.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Sorry I'm not able to get the point. The structures were re-tooled to be generic in/around 2004, right? Wouldn't that have been the time to consider the options?

Comment: @BobbyDigital Java chose to be "backwards-compatible" with generics; generics are only a compile-time enforcement. Instead of comparing C++ templates and Java generics (which are *entirely different* approaches), it would be more fitting to compare Java and .NET generics. In .NET, *new* types were added. That is `IList` and `IList<..>` are two *different* types in .NET while `List` and `List<..>` are both the *same* `List` type in Java.

Comment: I don't understand what it is you're asking. Templates/Generics (using the same data structure to contain different types) are completely orthogonal to inheritance in the class hierarchy of the container. The fact that Java's `Stack` extends `Vector` is a historical wart, and the official docs recommend against using it in new code.

Comment: This isn't about inheritance versus templates. This is about inheritance versus composition - Java's `Stack` *is-a* `Vector`, while C++'s `stack` *has-a* `deque` inside of it.

Comment: A lot of bad decisions went into the pre-Collections Java container classes. For example, `Vector` grows in fixed-size chunks, and everything had unnecessary locking that wasn't even very helpful in multithreaded code. Use a `LinkedList` or an `ArrayDeque` if you want a stack these days.

Comment: @user2357112: that's a fair argument but the unclear point I was making is the fact that it *might have-any* data structure that satisfies the contract which in this case is `vector`, `list` and `deque`. I regret bringing Java into the equation. It was really only to show the other possible approach.

Answer (score 3):

C++ collections and Java collections are very different. Java collections have an obvious type hierarchy, whereas most C++ collection types do not extend any other class, and templates are extensively used to support multiple collection types.

Although I don't know for sure, I imagine that the Java library developers made Stack a subclass of Vector because a stack is a collection of elements in a well defined order, so acts like a list, and by subclassing Vector they could get most of the implementation of the stack for free. This also has the benefit that you can use stacks in places where you need a list or a vector, for example you could pass a stack to a function that takes a list and iterates over it. Of course, c++ stacks are not iterable, so there is (intentianal or not) a very different semantics between the two stacks.

Finally, for your own code, if you are considering whether B should inherit  or contain A, first ask yourself if B is an A, or more specifically, if you would ever want to treat a B as an A by passing it to a function that expects an A, or returning it from a function that needs to return an A. If so you should use inheritance, otherwise you should probably use composition.

Answer (score 1):

The `Stack` class,  as well as `Vector`,  are legacy containers. They are left-overs of JDK1.0, they are based on an older design of the utils library, and are inefficient because of synchronization.

The preferred implementation of `Stack` in Java is given by implementations of the `Deque` interface (mainly `ArrayDeque` and `LinkedList`). You get the difference: in C++ one says that an stack has a given implementation. In Java one declares a class implementing the desired interface:

```
class ArrayDeque<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> 
implements Collection<E>, Deque<E>, Queue<E> //etc
```

When using such classes, always take the less specialized interface possible, for instance:

```
Deque<String> stack = new LinkedList<String>();
```